# How to open ternimal in new window with git tower

Tags: git-tower

git tower can open the current repository at the terminal,
Against the window of an already open terminal
`cd '/my/path/for/repo/`.

This command is ignored during execution such as webpack server.

Is there a way to open it in a new window when opening a terminal from git tower?

I am sorry if it was Google translation because it is English translation.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tower can only target the last active Terminal window.
Please make sure to have a Terminal window which can be used by Tower before calling Terminal.

<sub>Disclaimer: I'm with the support team for Tower</sub>

Comment: Are you planning to add ternimal in a new window?

Comment: I don't have an ETA but this is planned. @tadashi